# Is there a CSS selector for elements lacking an attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I understand that css rules can target elements specified by attribute values, e.g.:

```
input[type="text"] {}
```

Can I make a rule that targets elements which *omit* a certain attribute?  For example, can I target  elements that lack an href or  elements that don't specify a type?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can follow this pattern:

```
a:not([href])
input:not([type])
```

The [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) is used to select elements with the specified attribute.

[`:not`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not) is supported in all modern browsers and IE9+, if you need IE8 or lower support you're out of luck.

Comment: +1 Here's a demo for the curious: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2sHD/2/ Side note: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `<a>` *requires* an href attribute to be present in order to be, yknow, valid HTML.

Comment: @Wesley it doesn't, an a element can be simply an anchor, with only the name attribute

Comment: Ah yes that's right, not sure where I got that idea. I think I was thinking of something else entirely.

Comment: Also worth noting that it's possible to select ONLY all elements that contain NO (custom) attributes. I was racking my brain for a bit before arriving at the admittedly obvious answer. While you can't do something like `foo:not(foo[*]){ color: red; }`, you can do a standard CSS cascade like `foo{ color: red; } foo[green]{ color: green; } foo[blue]{ color: blue; }` to define a "default" value. This has the nice side effect of making any other/unrecognized value fallback to the default, instead of defining things like `foo[normal],foo[default]{ color:red; }`.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me was to place `a:link { }` within my code.

I also tried

`a:not([href])
input:not([href=""])
input:not([href~=""])`

But for a **.scss file** with multiple a tags used as standard code blocks (not my idea), this was the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

For links you can simply use:

```
a { color: red; }
a:link { color: green; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHTXS/ no need for javascript.

For form attributes, use the not attribute pattern noted above `input:not([type])` and if you need to support older versions of IE, I'd probably add a class and use an IE specific style sheet linked with conditional comments.

Comment: While this is a clever answer for anchors, it applies only to anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set different style to a and a href

Check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uy2sj/

Comment: As my comment stated in the below answer, this would only be useful for anchors. While the title may state anchors, the OP specifies all elements and even includes an input example.