# Is it possible to select all elements which do not have any CSS class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, anchor

[The W3C Recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) defines the ability to select any anchor which has a defined class by using `A[CLASS]{/*Code*/}`, but is there an antecedent?

**Can I select all anchors that do NOT have a class?**

My instinct is to use `A[~CLASS]{/*Code*/}`, but that isn't documented, and `A[CLASS=]{/*Code*/}` selects all anchors which have a class name which is an empty string (for instance, `<A CLASS="" HREF="http://example.com/">This anchor has a class, but it's empty.</A>`).

### Example usage

---

In this code, I only want classless links to be green.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="http://example.com/externalUneditableStyles.CSS" />
<STYLE>
A.deadLink{
color:#FF0000 !important;
}
A{
color:#00FF00;
}

</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<A HREF="http://fakesite.not/" CLASS="deadLink">This link is red, as specified by the CSS above.</A>
<A HREF="http://example.com/">This link is green, as specified by the CSS above.</A>
<A HREF="#/childpage/" CLASS="childLink">This is a link to a child page, and is styled by external uneditable CSS. That CSS doesn't specify a color, so it is green, even though that might not be the intended effect.</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Actually, `A[CLASS=]` is a syntax error. `A[CLASS=""]` is the correct way to express it.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010323/use-css-selector-to-select-all-div-elements-with-some-class-but-without-style-a?rq=1

Comment: @pst thanks, but the way you wrote it also changed it from a question to a statement, but with a question mark at the end. Also, I was editing it when you changed it, so it was changed back. I'll try to make it more to your liking.

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes, I have a tendency to do that with "question" titles :( I think this is a good title now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for <a> tags lacking a href attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166259/is-there-a-css-selector-for-a-tags-lacking-a-href-attribute)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
a:not([class]) {
    /*some styling here*/
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/T8FjX/).

Comment: Does htis work with multiple attributes? Can it be used to select elements that have both no class and no id?

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes, use `a:not([class]):not([id])`. Here's a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/En4k5/).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what cascading is for, if you do:

```
a { color: #000; } /* this targets all anchors */
```

Then after this in your stylesheet you can do

```
a.classname { color: #ffcc00; } /* to override the color for the once with the classname class defined. */
```

I hope that's clarifies your question.

Comment: This questions is not asking for how to *select A's with a particular class*. It is asking how to *select A's with **no** class*.

Comment: that's what a {} with no class does.

Comment: That will match *all A's*. Not the set of *A's with **no** class*.

Comment: This becomes cumbersome when you have many classes. I'm dealing with a website which has hundreds of types of anchors (it's a wiki; it has regular, dead, external, edit, page tabs, etc.).

Comment: I guess the point @pst is trying to make is that there's a difference between using the cascade to override *general* styles, and *selecting* specific elements.

Comment: @Abody97's solution is the best in that case. As Supuhstar figured out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the `.foo:not(.bar)`-pseudo selector. I also advise you not to code tags in caps. I believe it is allowed in HTML5, but not in XHTML. Even so, the practice is frowned upon.

Comment: A bit late to suggest this, don't you think? See the accepted answer :P

Comment: Also it's invalid to use quotes in CSS `:not()`, even though jQuery allows it.